# Value too long for type character

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL file that I want to execute in a Postgresql database.The file has SQL statements to create both tables and composite-types and then insert some values into the created tables and composite-types.

```
CREATE TYPE address_object AS (
    state char(2),
    zip char(10)
);

CREATE TYPE embedded_address AS (
    state char(2),
    zip char(10),
    preaddr address_object  
);

CREATE TYPE address_value AS (
    state char(2),
    zip char(10)
);

CREATE TYPE person AS (
    name char(20),
    age numeric,
    address address_object
);

CREATE TABLE customerval (
    custno numeric,
    addr address_value
);

CREATE TABLE extaddr OF address_object;

CREATE TABLE customerobj (
    custno numeric,
    addr address_object  
);

CREATE TABLE embextaddr OF embedded_address;

CREATE TABLE emp (
    emp_id numeric,
    emp_info person
);

CREATE TABLE empref (
    emp_id numeric,
    emp_info person  
);

CREATE TABLE extper OF person;

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO customerval VALUES (100, ROW('CA'::char(2), '94065'::char(10)));
INSERT INTO extaddr VALUES (ROW(LEFT('CA', 2), CAST('94065' AS CHAR(10))));
INSERT INTO extaddr VALUES (ROW(LEFT('CA',2),CAST('98765' AS char(10))));
INSERT INTO extaddr VALUES (ROW(LEFT('CA' ,2),CAST('95117' AS char(10))));
INSERT INTO embextaddr VALUES (ROW(LEFT('CA',2),CAST('95117' AS char(10), NULL))));
```

When I run the file, I get some errors, for instance for the first insert statement:
ERROR:  value too long for type character(2)
2STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO extaddr VALUES (ROW(LEFT('CA', 2), CAST('94065' AS CHAR(10))));
psql:file.sql:53: ERROR:  value too long for type character(2)

The tables and the composite-types are created in the database and the first insert are successful. The last three insert statements fails due the error above.

````
INSERT INTO extaddr VALUES (ROW(LEFT('CA', 2), CAST('94065' AS CHAR(10))));```.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the outer [`row()` constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS).

You might've assumed that [`CREATE TABLE my_table OF my_type;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-TYPE-NAME) creates a table with a single column of type `my_type` - that's not the case. [From the doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-TYPE-NAME)

> When a typed table is created, then the data types of the columns are determined by the underlying composite type

Each row follows the structure of the type and you only need to encapsulate values when you have a type-in-type sort of situation, like `customerval.address_value` in the first insert. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/RSqjWJZx)

```sql
INSERT INTO customerval VALUES (100, ROW('CA','94065')::address_value);
INSERT INTO extaddr VALUES ('CA', '94065'),
                           ('CA', '98765'),
                           ('CA', '95117');
INSERT INTO embextaddr VALUES ('CA','95117',NULL);
```

I'm guessing the `left()`s are there because you suspected `'CA'` is somehow too long for `char(2)`. What's really happening is that PostgreSQL is only seeing a single value coming in (resulting from your `row()` call) and it's trying to write it into the first column, which it finds is of different type `char(2)`. So it tries to cast the whole thing - doesn't fit, hence the error. [Here's the doc on that:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.5)

> The values supplied by the `VALUES` clause or *query* are associated with the explicit or implicit column list left-to-right.
>
> Each column not present in the explicit or implicit column list will be filled with a default value, either its declared default value or null if there is none.
>
> If the expression for any column is not of the correct data type, automatic type conversion will be attempted.

Field number mismatch is only reported if you're trying to stuff *too many* values into a table with *too few columns*, but in this case, it assumes you only have one value (resulting from `row()`) that goes into the first column (`char(2)`). Type mismatch is reported on that failed automatic cast attempt.

---

If you're getting those values packed like that, you can also just unpack them with a [`().*`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION):

```sql
INSERT INTO extaddr VALUES ((row('CA', '94065')).*),
                           ((row('CA', '98765')).*),
                           ((row('CA', '95117')).*);
```